# Posting to Facebook Wall with PHP. Why does it only work in Firefox?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

I want to post in my Facebook page Wall a message through my web page. I manage to do this with the next code:

```
<?php
$config['baseurl']  =   "http://....facebook/index.php";

if ($fbme){
    if (isset($message)){
        try {
            $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> $message, 'picture'=> $Image,'cb' => ''));
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            d($e);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I am using the $config in the login and logout functions:

```
function login(){
     document.location.href = "<?=$config['baseurl']?>";
 }
 function logout(){
     document.location.href = "<?=$config['baseurl']?>";
 }
```

Also I am using a facebook button for login:

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" onlogin="parent.location='http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=<?php echo $uid ?>'" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
```

Ok. Now when I click a button in my web site I go to my facebook application and first of all if asks me to login. Then when I am logged in I go immediately to my profile page for see the message in my Wall. everything works ok. The problem is that when I am refreshing my facebook page I get again the same message in my Wall, so I have it twice. This happens only two times.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I changed the login function and it worked:

```
 function login(){
        //document.location.href = "<?=$config['baseurl']?>";
        parent.location = "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=<?=$uid ?>"
   }
```

My problem is that this thing works only in Firefox, not in IE, Safari and Chrome. Does anyone know how to solve it??

Thanks